# Magento2 Addtocart is not working after transfer site from one server to another

Tags: magento2, addtocart, server-setup

can you please suggest me I have transferred my site from one server to
another, all Magento functionality works except add to cart.

And checkout cart add controller return 500 error

I am getting below error in debug.log

> Request validation failed for action
> "Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor"
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException(code: 0):
> Invalid request received at
> /home/simplecity/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/CsrfValidator.php:105)"}
> []

Comment: Please add the error you're getting, check error and systemlog. Check in the network and console tab on dev console ito check if you're getting any error there.

Comment: yes @VivekKumar error addedd

Comment: can you add url here where you get this error and menu.xml file for the same ?

Comment: This error is in debug.log not in any console or network error

Answer (score 1):

I Ignored Validation use plugin as below :

Module_Name/etc/di.xml add:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator">
    <plugin name="csrf_validator_skip" type="Module\Name\Plugin\CsrfValidatorSkip" />
</type>
```

Module_Name/Plugin/CsrfValidatorSkip.php

```
namespace Module\Name\Plugin;

class CsrfValidatorSkip
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $action
     */
    public function aroundValidate(
        $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $request,
        $action
    ) {
        /* Magento 2.1.x, 2.2.x */
        if ($request->getModuleName() == 'name') {
            return; // Skip CSRF check
        }
        $proceed($request, $action); // Proceed Magento 2 core functionalities
    }
}
```

My Error was as below:

> main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action
> "Module\Name\Controller\HtmlRedirect\Response\Interceptor"
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException(code: 0):
> Invalid request received at
> MagentoRoot/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/CsrfValidator.php:105)"}
> []

Comment: thanks it's solved my issue